# In Gimp, how to resize a Selection after it's been used?

Tags: gimp, resize, selections

The question is probably not clear on one line! Here some details:

1. made a circular selection (*Ellipse Select Tool*) to get a perfect circle
2. just after, using the mouse, resized that selection by clicking a corner of that selection (See pic below, hovering the bottom-right side of the circle makes a "Resize selection" mouse cursor appear)
3. then did "*Inverse Selection*" and erased part of the picture (*Eraser*), while the selection in 2. was not affected
4. finally did "*Inverse Selection*" again to get back my initial selection: Selection is untouched, same as after 2.

However, now I'd like to resize the selection again, and went back to "*Ellipse Selection Tool*". But when the mouse is hovered over the Selection corner, the mouse pointer doesn't change to the "Resize Selection" as it did in 2. And clicking anything will lose that selection. This is because (while selection was not affected) some other operations were done in between.

[image]

How, after 4., the same selection can be resized (as I did in 2.) ; how to get the "Resize selection" feature back?

Actually, I just want to enlarge the initial selection circle, from the same center: maybe there is another way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the elliptic selection tool, click into the selection.

This doesn't restore the selection per se. It rather starts a new selection within the bounding box of the existing one, but will come close in most cases. In your case, it should be indistinguishable from the original selection.

Comment: In this case I need to start from the center of the existing one, which is not shown

Comment: You don't need the center. In your case, the one click will get you a selection that is indistinguishable from your original one.

Comment: Doesn't do that on my version 2.8.10 (Linux)

Comment: Can you add a screenshot that includes your tool options right before you click inside of the existing selection?

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking that perhaps setting two quick guides onto the centre of the original selection and then creating a new one might be relatively easy and quick, but again - not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

So far, found only one way to enlarge the selection without losing center...

```
Select menu > Grow
```

Not as flexible as the initial mouse resizer, but will do the job for now.