# In GIMP, how to resize a rotated selection box?

Tags: gimp, resize, selections, rotate

I've tried selecting a rectangle and rotating the box with the rotate tool in a blank layer, but clicking in the box doesn't seem to allow me to resize the rotated box.

I am attempting to remove lens flare by subtracting a rotated gradient that is restricted to a box, but it is quite hard to get the size of the box correct before rotating it.  Unfortunately, if I click in the selection box after rotating it, GIMP seems to forget that the box was there.

The advice given here: [How to edit existing rectangle selection in GIMP?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/91659/how-to-edit-existing-rectangle-selection-in-gimp) therefore doesn't seem to work.  Is there any other way to resize a rotated selection box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to click on the Transform "Selection" button in the Rotate Tool options, then you can rotate the selection.  It's the same with all the transform tools.

[image]

Comment: Thank was exactly what I was looking for.  Very helpful!

Comment: Actually, not quite what I was looking for, as you cannot click in the rotated selection to resize it.  However, you can, as it were, 'externally' resize the region with the other tools.